# Is there an alternative to elrm (Exact logistic regression) in R - the elrm package is not available in repository

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a simple binary logistic regression, but one of my cells has a 0. Because of this, I wanted to run exact logistic regression but I get that package elrm is not available for R 3.6.2.

I researched online and found you could install from archive, but I have never done that before.

I tried the following, but still got the message that "ERROR: dependency 'coda' is not available for package 'elrm'
elrmurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/elrm/elrm_1.2.3.tar.gz"

> install.packages(elrmurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

I'm very out of my depth with this one but would appreciate any guidance on either 1) how to properly install the elrm package from archive (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/elrm/) or 2) potential alternative packages that might allow me to do exact logistic regression in R.

Comment: did you try installing `coda` separately, first? using `remotes::install_version()` (after looking at the archive to find out the latest version number)

Answer (score 2):

Try  :

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
install_github("cran/elrm")
```

You probably already thought about it, but you could also collapse or delete levels in order to have enough observations to do a regular logistic regression with glm